# Create config file when running Docker container with Compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables

I have the following `Dockerfile`

```
FROM node:10.8.0-alpine as builder

# Set working directory
RUN mkdir /usr/src
RUN mkdir /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Add /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin to $PATH
ENV PATH /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# Get build arguments coming from .env file
ARG API_URL
ENV API_URL "$API_URL"

# Create config file from environment variables
RUN echo "API_URL = $API_URL" > ./app.cfg

# Install and cache app dependencies
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/package.json
RUN npm install
RUN npm install react-scripts@1.1.1 -g
COPY . /usr/src/app
RUN npm run build

# Production environment
FROM nginx:1.15.2-alpine
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

And I use the following `docker-compose.yml` file to build my Docker image

```
version: '3'
services:

  app:
    container_name: data-quality-app
    restart: always
    image: data-quality-app
    build:
      context: ./app
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        - API_URL=${API_URL}
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    ports:
      - 80:80
    networks:
      - default

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: data-quality-network

volumes:
  data-quality-db-volume:
    external: true
```

Note the file `.env` contains the environment variable `API_URL=http://0.0.0.0:5433/graphql`

All this works pretty well, but when I run my container with Docker Compose:

`$ docker-compose up app`

I would like to overwrite the file `app.cfg` in the container in order to replace the value of `API_URL` by its current value in the file `.env`.

I have tried to add the following `ENTRYPOINT` in `Dockerfile` but it did not work:

```
[...]
# Create config file to from environment variables
RUN echo "API_URL = $API_URL" > ./app.cfg
ENTRYPOINT echo "API_URL = $API_URL" > ./app.cfg
[...]
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should write an entrypoint script that does the required setup, then runs the command passed to the container.

`entrypoint.sh`:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
if [ -n "$API_URL" ]; then
  echo "API_URL = $API_URL" > app.cfg
fi
exec "$@"
```

`Dockerfile` (final stage):

```
FROM nginx:1.15.2-alpine
COPY entrypoint.sh /
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

You can debug this by running something like

```
docker build -t mynginx .
docker run --rm -it -e API_URL=http://test mynginx sh
```

which will run the entrypoint script passing it "sh" as the command; that will set up the `app.cfg` file and then launch the debug shell (and not nginx).